# If $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers larger than $2$, then $pq + 1 $ is never prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I am trying to prove the following: If $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers larger than $2$, then $pq + 1 $ is never prime. Any ideas?

Comment: It is even, since $p,q>2$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Curious that none of the answers so far gets this very simple argument completely right (without implicitly assuming at some point that primes are always odd). [At least they didn't at the time of writing.]

Let $p,q$ be odd primes. Then since $p,q$ are odd, $pq+1$ is even. If it were prime, one would have $pq+1=2$ since that is the only even prime number. But then $pq=1$ while odd primes are${}\geq3$, clearly a contradiction.

(Alternatively for the final phrase: "but $1$ has no prime divisors at all" or "but $1$ is not a prime number".)

Comment: What's wrong with assuming that primes "at some point" (i.e. after 2) are *always odd*?  The indivisibility of integers by integers other than itself and one is the very definition of primality.  Since any even number >= 2 is divisible by two, the assumption that all primes > 2 are odd is completely valid.

Comment: @par: I meant at some point in the argument ("after $2$" is not "at some point"). For instance Digital Brain starts saying (all) primes are odd; Jasper Joy and AaronMaroja just show evenness (and JiK only vaguely alludes to it), suggesting that this implies non-primeness. I do know there that $p>2$ prime implies $p$ odd; indeed my argument mentions that $2$ is the only even prime number.

Comment: I see what you mean.  The question specifically says "odd primes", and I think that's so fundamental that you don't have to explicitly call out 2 as the only even prime.  That said, you did make clever use of that fact in your proof.  I always enjoy a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Oh you're absolutely right.  I saw the question after the first edit and thought it was the original.

Answer (score 39):

If $p$ and $q$ are primes larger than $2$, then they are odd. It follows that $pq+1$ is even and larger than $2$, so $pq+1$ is composite.

Answer (score 11):

Another kind of hint: If you have no idea where to start in this kind of problems, you can always try some small values and try if you can see a pattern.
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
3 \cdot 3 + 1 &=& 10 \\
3 \cdot 5 + 1 &=& 16 \\
5 \cdot 5 + 1 &=& 26 \\
3 \cdot 7 + 1 &=& 22 \\ 
5 \cdot 7 + 1 &=& 36 \\
&\vdots&
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:**

Since $p,q > 2$ and the product of two odd numbers is odd then $pq + 1$ must be even.

Comment: A very strange use of "Since". The conclusion in the previous sentence was already proved.

Answer (score 0):

If $p,q>2$ and $p,q\in\Bbb P$ then $2\not\mid p,q$. This is obvious.

If $p,q$ are odd then $2\mid (p*q+1)$, what make obvious that is not prime.